# How to make a multiple select element export as a single column for each selection option?

Tags: drupal, drupal-8, drupal-webform

This is for the Webforms Project for Drupal 8.

I have a table select element for days of the week. When I export the results I get a cell with "Monday, Tuesday, Friday". I would like the multiple select to a separate column for each day of the week.

```
Day_Mon | Day_Tues | Day_Wed | Day_Thurs | Day_Fri | Day_Sat | Day_Sun
----------------------------------------------------------------------
   x    |    x     |         |           |    x    |         |
```

Comment: You have not provided anywhere near enough information. What is "table select element" ? How are you "exporting the results"?

Comment: Sorry, this is for the webforms project in Drupal 8. I tagged those, but didn't describe it above. Anyways, table select is one of the out-of-the-box elements to choose from. It makes an HTML table with check boxes for each day of the week. The export is the out-of-the-box csv export.